# Function onDataChange() is called from the previous fragment firebase android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-architecture-navigation

I ran into a rather strange problem. In my fragment there is a code for adding an item to the database through the `child().setValue()`. In another fragment there is user authorization, where it checks if the user exists, it is also implemented using the `onDataChange()` function.

Check user function [**AuthFragment**]:

```
private fun checkUserExist() {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    ref.child(auth.uid!!)
        .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                // User exist
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_authSecondStepFragment_to_authCompletedFragment)
            } else {
                // User not exist
                saveUser()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            throw error.toException()
        }
    })
}
```

Adding item to database function [**AddingToDatabaseFragment**]:

```
private fun addToFavorite() {
    val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

    with(args) {
        hashMap["id"] = getPlaceId()
        hashMap["name"] = currentPlace.name
        hashMap["location"] = currentPlace.description
        hashMap["image"] = currentPlace.image
        hashMap["description"] = currentPlace.description
    }

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    ref.child(getProfileUid()!!)
        .child("Favorites")
        .child(getPlaceId())
        .setValue(hashMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Succesfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

Actually, the problem is that when successfully authorizing through the `onDataChange()` function, I get to another fragment, where I can already add some item to the database, and when adding (respectively, changing the database), the `onDataChange()` function from of the **PREVIOUS** authorization fragment, in my case `findNavController()` is called from a fragment that I am not even in, which causes the application to crash. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `addValueEventListener`, you are registering a permanent listener. The only way to deactivate that listener is by [detaching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners) it, typically when it goes out of scope.

I usually try to put my attaching and detaching of listeners in the opposite life-cycle events of my activities. So if I attach in `onStart` I'll detach in `onStop`, and same for `onUnpause`/`onResume`.

For fragments you should follow the same logic, so `onAttach` -> `onDetach`, or `onStart` -> `onStop`, or `onPause` -> `onResume`.

Comment: It's incredible, I've been struggling with this problem for over a week, thanks a lot!